# TFS Build Task to add IDs to our HTML tags automatically

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have an Angular application that we are developing. During development many tags were not given any ids because they were not needed. Now the QA team wants to automate the test cases using Selenium. The tool prefers ids on our HTML tags so the automated tests can recognize elements. We are now being asked to add ids to all the HTML tags.

My question is, can this be add dynamically at build time? We are using TFS for our builds and deployments. We will use a specific convention for the ids so that they are generated consistently (e.g. page name + angular selector name + html tag or something similar).

We want to do this because we want to keep our production and dev builds as clean and succinct as possible. If there's a way to target only our automation/QA builds that would be ideal. The other benefit is that there are other applications in our organization that could benefit from this as they have similar requirements.

Comment: Why would this question be downvoted or flagged for removal?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the files programming through PowerShell or other task of TFS build.